# Blazor object serialization is truncated

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have not been programming with Blazor for very long and am having some serialization problems. I have a server side blazor app and a client side as well in the same solution. I have a server side controller that is sent an ID then retrieves the data for the object, builds the object and then returns the object to the client. The object is fairly large but is only a maximum of 5 levels deep. most of the object is returned but the rest is truncated. I have had a similar problem in MVC and was able to fix it by changing the maxBufferSize and maxMessageSize in the web.config file. Since there is no web.config file how and where do I make the changes?
Serialization is built in JASON

server side looks like

```
public SalesDeal FindDeal(int dealID, bool lockDeal)
{
  SET_EMPLOYEES user = new SET_EMPLOYEES();
  SalesControl sControl = SalesData.SalesControls.FindByControlID(dealID, user.CNN);
  SalesDeal deal = new SalesDeal { SalesControl = sControl };
  try
  {
    Task[] tasks = new Task[26];
    tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.AHLife = SalesData.AHLife.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.BankInformation = SalesData.Banks.FindByID(sControl.BANK_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.Company = SET_COMPANIESManager.FindByID(sControl.COMPANY_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.FinanceManager = SET_EMPLOYEESManager.FindByID(sControl.FinManager_EMPLOYEE_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[4] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesAdds = SalesData.Adds.FindBySalesControlID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[5] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesCommGross = SalesData.CommGross_Data.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[6] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesCustomer = CustomerManager.FindCustomerByID(sControl.CUSTOMER_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[7] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesFinancial = SalesData.Financial.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[8] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesRebates = SalesData.Rebates.FindBySalesControlID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[9] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesGap = SalesData.Gap_Data.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[10] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesGapProvider = SalesData.GapProviders.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[11] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesLocCharges = SalesData.LocCharges.FindBySALESCONTROL_ID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[12] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesLocParams = SalesData.LocParams.FindByDealerID(sControl.COMPANY_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[13] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesManager = SET_EMPLOYEESManager.FindByID(sControl.SalesManager_EMPLOYEE_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[14] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesRep1 = SET_EMPLOYEESManager.FindByID(sControl.SalesRep1_EMPLOYEE_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[15] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesRep2 = SET_EMPLOYEESManager.FindByID(sControl.Salesrep2_EMPLOYEE_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[16] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesService = SalesData.Service_Data.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[17] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesServiceProvider = SalesData.ServiceProviders.FindByID(sControl.SERVICE_PROVIDER_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[18] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesWarranty = SalesData.WarrantyData.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[19] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesWarrantyProvider = SalesData.WarrantyProvidersData.FindByID(sControl.SERVICE_PROVIDER_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[20] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SecondaryCustomer = CustomerManager.FindCustomerByID(sControl.SEC_CUSTOMER_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[21] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.Trades = SalesData.UpTrades.FindBySalesControlID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[22] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.Vehicle = SalesData.SaleInventory.FindByID(sControl.INVENTORY_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[23] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.SalesPlan = SalesData.CRM_SALES_MENU_Data.FindBySALESCONTROL(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[24] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.DealCalcValues = SalesData.CalculationValues_Data.FindByID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN); });
    tasks[25] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { deal.GridRates = SalesData.SALES_GRIDRATES_Data.FindBySALESCONTROL_ID(sControl.SALESCONTROL_ID, user.CNN).Values.ToList(); });
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    return deal;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return null;
  }
}
```

And the client side looks like...

```
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  string urlString = string.Format("CWSalesDeal/FindDeal?dealid={0}&lockDeal={1}", dealid, true);
 try
 {

   deal = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<SalesDeal>(urlString);
   if (deal == null)
     throw new Exception("is null");
   controller = new SalesDealController(deal);

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " " + ex?.InnerException?.Message);
 }
}
```

Comment: How are you serializing it? Converting to JSON? gRPC? Something else?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified.. Built in Jason..      server side looks like                                                                      [HttpGet]
    public SalesDeal FindDeal(int dealID, bool lockDeal)
 {

Comment: Add all the code involved in sending & receiving. Also estimate  "fairly large" ik kB.

Comment: only getting 14.58kb back.

Comment: That exact number each time?

Comment: yes.. seems to be

Comment: Anyway, test the server first, use PostMan or similar. The ReceiveBuffer is by default 2GB.

Comment: I did use postman and that was how I found that the data is truncated. stops the same place every time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I'm an idiot.. After looking through all classes and sub classes I finally found the problem.. there were 2 properties that were using a Dictionary instead of a list. Dictionary is not supported. Thanks for listening!

Answer (score -1):

You might try replacing the default serializer with Newtonsoft: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

This has solved many problems.